# What is the interface between functional analysis and algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, big-list, big-picture, reading-list

This is a very open ended curiosity of mine and I would be grateful to hear any comments in this direction. In particular I am interested in functional analysis/algebraic geometry books/papers references which show this bridge from functional analysis into algebraic geometry.

---

I am not sure if it's related but what are the good references for "functional analysis on manifolds"? Like how do we characterize the function space based on the domain manifold properties or for specific manifolds like say spheres.  (the related things I see are courses like, [Pierre Albin's lecture notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Epalbin/Math524.Spring2012/LectureNotesMay1.pdf) or [Yaiza Canzani's ones](https://canzani.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/12623/2023/07/notes.png), but these seem more about understanding specific differential operators on manifolds rather than the space of functions on a manifold)

Like is there any meaning to wondering, "What is the Hilbert space of functions on a sphere?"

Comment: There are pretty natural answers to your second paragraph.  A Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ has a canonical volume form $\mathrm{Vol}$ which induces a Borel measure.  Then $(M, \mathrm{Vol})$ is a measure space and so the most natural Hilbert space of functions on $M$ is $L^2(M, \mathrm{Vol})$.  We can also consider Sobolev spaces; for instance, the $H^1$ norm is defined by $\|f\|_{H^1(M)} = \int_M (|f|^2 + g(\nabla f, \nabla f))\,d\mathrm{Vol}$.  Is that what you are looking for?  I don't see how it helps build a bridge to algebraic geometry, but then again, I know little of the latter.

Comment: One important connection between functional analysis and algebraic geometry is Hodge theory, for which you need to understand the Laplacian (elliptic) as well as some related operators. A concise reference are the books of C. Voisin.

Comment: Differential geometry would seem more natural than algebraic geometry in this context. How much algebraic geometry are you familiar with?

Comment: You might want to consider asking your two questions in separate posts.  At least the second part might be considered "too elementary" by some (though it seems okay to me), so http://math.stackexchange.com is another option.

Comment: I think, for the second question (i.e. functional analysis on manifolds), the right "buzzwords" are Geometric Analysis, Global Analysis, Geometric Measure Theory and similar. If you search for these, you'll find plenty of references.

Comment: The interface was, I believe, Alexander Grothendieck ;-)

Comment: Another direction, where so called $L^2$-methods enter, is the study of (algebraic) vector bundles and positivity. There is whole manuscript by Demailly dedicated to this and literally called "Analytic Methods in Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: To repeat myself: why do you say algebraic geometry rather than differential geometry? Which is the one that you are hoping to be connected to functional analysis?

Comment: @YemonChoi I am looking for a connection to "algebraic geometry". The "spectral" theory, as say done in the two references I gave, seem to be more of a connection to differential geometry. If the same you are looking at is an algebraic variety then does that description lead to an understanding of the function space on that variety?

Comment: @NateEldredge Do you have a reference which talks of these Sobolev spaces and Hilbert spaces on the sphere? That looks like a starting point!

Comment: @gradstudent Thank you for your response. It still seems to me that you are hoping for a connection where there is no reason to expect one, but since I am not an algebraic geometer perhaps I am overlooking something. Note that the _categories_ in question look rather different!

Comment: For instance, see Part 2, Section 48.3 of [these notes](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/lecture_notes.htm).  https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/sobolev-spaces-on-manifolds/ also looks useful.

Comment: Noncommutative Geometry is what immediately comes to mind for me.

Comment: @Jake Why on earth does it come to mind for you? What about Connes's NC(D)G is algebro-geometric?

Comment: Take a look at the theory of algebraic analysis. Things like Sato's hyperfunctions, microlocal analysis, singular support, etc. A good (albeit terrifying) reference is Kashiwara and Schapira's "Sheaves on Manifolds".

Comment: Well, as for Hilber spaces *tout court* on manifolds, i.e. $L^2(M,\mu)$, there isn't much to say: if the measure is the one induced by a Riemannian metric (which seems to be the case you might be interested in) then, up to a null measure set, $(M,\mu)$ is equivalent to an open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with the corresponding Riemannian volume form $\mu'$ transported on it, hence $L^2(M,\mu)=L^2(U,\mu')$.

Comment: There are some conceptual links between the two. For example, the Gelfand–Naimark theorem provides almost an anti-equivalence between locally compact Hausdorff spaces and commutative $C^*$-algebras. In algebraic geometry, on the other hand, spaces are in some sense *defined* in terms of the functions on them, turning this principle around. In both cases, people have been looking for non-commutative analogues. This is still an active area of research (well, two somewhat unrelated active areas of research, as @YemonChoi's last comment shows).

Comment: Since this question has been bumped to the top again, can I just reiterate my view that it is too broad; it almost seems to be asking "where are places in one area where I might see some parts of the other area?"

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at how the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch can be deduced as a special case of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem.  The idea is to consider the hodge operator $\overline{\partial} + \overline{\partial}^\ast$ on the bundle of differential forms with values in a given holomorphic vector bundle $V$ over a complex manifold $X$.  This is an elliptic differential operator, and the index theorem says that its Fredholm index is the integral of the product of the Chern class of $V$ and the Todd class of $X$.  On the other hand the Fredholm index is the holomorphic Euler characteristic of $V$ by Hodge theory, yielding HRR.

The proof of the index theorem invariably uses a lot of functional analysis - either analysis of heat kernels, pseudo-differential operator theory, or operator algebras, depending on your preferences.  This provides a foundation for a number of other interactions between algebraic geometry and functional analysis, like generalizations to holomorphic non-commutative spaces or analytic counterparts of Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch.

Answer (score 6):

One connection (which is perhaps more geometric analytic than functional analytic), is the relationship between [$K$-stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-stability), which is an algebro-geometric notion and the existence of constant scalar curvature Kahler metrics. In particular, the Yau–Tian–Donaldson conjecture states that there is a deep connection between these two notions.

**Yau–Tian–Donaldson conjecture**: A smooth polarised variety $(X,L)$ admits a constant scalar curvature Kähler metric in the class of $c_1(L)$ if and only if the pair $(X,L)$ is K-polystable.

Initially, this might seem like more of a connection between algebraic and differential geometry. However, the existence of a constant scalar curvature Kahler metric boils down to the existence for a particularly nasty PDE, so the work in this area is quite analytic (see, e.g., [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00656) of Chen and Cheng). I should note that one direction of this conjecture is known (existence of a cscK metric implies $K$-polystability for polarized varieties). At present, the other direction is still open, although it was proven for Fano manifolds in 2012.

Answer (score 5):

As an example in which algebraic geometry and functional analysis (mildly) interact: in the book [*Several complex variables with connections to algebraic geometry and Lie groups*](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-46) by J.L.Taylor, if I remember correctly, there is a chapter on [GAGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry) in which sheaves of Fréchet spaces are considered.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if this is what you are looking for but I heard people speaking of Banach Algebraic Geometry. I can also note the fascinating work of Semyon Alesker (using algebra-geometric tools on say space of convex bodies).

On a high level there is certain similarities between the ideas in two fields. But, I personally prefer more concrete connections better. The real algebraic objects coming out of optimization problems, or convex objects with a lot symmetry coming out of Quantum Information Theory seems to be forcing an interface between algebraic geometry and convex geometric analysis ( local theory of Banach spaces if you like).  There is also new developments in random real geometry which seems to require a blend of func analysis with AG.

Comment: I'll just point out -- my vague understanding is that the algebro-geometric interest in Banach algebras comes from their use in rigid analytic geometry -- it's not just an abstract thing you do for its intrinsic interest.